# unscd - statistic option not working

Tags: linux, debian

I just installed unscd on debian jessie :

```
ii  unscd                          0.51-1+b2                          amd64        Micro Name Service Caching Daemon
```

Configuration looks like :

```
server-user unscd
debug-level 0

enable-cache            passwd  yes
positive-time-to-live   passwd  600
negative-time-to-live   passwd  20
suggested-size          passwd  1001
check-files             passwd  yes

enable-cache            group   yes
positive-time-to-live   group   3600
negative-time-to-live   group   60
suggested-size          group   1001
check-files             group   yes

enable-cache            hosts   yes
positive-time-to-live   hosts   3600
negative-time-to-live   hosts   20
suggested-size          hosts   1001
check-files             hosts   yes
```

But when I want to check the statistics with the following command :

```
nscd -g
```

I got no output. Return code is just 0

Any idea on what goes wrong ? Or maybe I missed something ?

Comment: Maybe the nscd program is not what you think it is. Sometimes programs have similar names (and commands), and that is bad i know, but it happens. For what your nscd was made for? II ask that for you because this -g parameter are not listed on Debian's nscd named "Name Service Cache Daemon"

Comment: I use unscd package for caching LDAP queries and to make faster queries to my LDAP server (user and group). I found the -g option from  man nscd

Comment: you point me to the right direction, the package nscd has the -g switch but unscd doesn't have it. So I guess this is a wrong description in man page for unscd package ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the traditional version of nscd to do what you want, so:

```
apt-get remove unscd 
apt-get install nscd
```

unscd is not what you are expecting, and appear to be an independent version of nscd (depending on less packets):
See https://packages.debian.org/pt-br/jessie/unscd for more information.